# indexing ,recursing efficiency

Tags: python, indexing

I am currently a student learning python right now and I was wondering if you could help me with some questions regarding recursing, indexing, and converting hex into binary.

1. If I increase the length of a string to a certain point which method will fail first and why? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fpYU.png)
2. Using `.format` and naive method to convert hex into binary which is more efficient and why? and if I were to use a string of 200 hex digits how do I determine the relative speed of one method over the other[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54tpa.png)

Hope you can help me out!! Thank you.

Comment: Which methods for increasing the length of string have you attempted? [Timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is a Python library for timing small code snippets that may be of use to you.

Comment: Yeap I am using Time to increase the length of string but I'm not sure whether will recursing or indexing fail first.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I have entered the code in the link after each questions. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: You can use triple backticks ` around code to format it as such. Please post your code in the question